# unknown column in field list django after syncdb

Tags: mysql, django

Doing some upgrades on a Django app.

Need to update the database.
Have added the new features in the model and in the database.
Have run syncDb,- it worked fine.

But the app don't allow the new changes.... get - "unknown column in field list".

Have read about south, but I'am just doing some work on the app for the moment, don't wanna add anything that is not orginal.

Any ideas how to sync the db and the app?

Thanks

Comment: make changes in db manually if you dont want to use south or you can delete table in db if you dont need current data and run syncdb

Comment: If you go through the path of re-creating the database, you can save your data with `python manage.py dumpdata --indent=4 >> dump.json` and then repopulate the database with `python manage.py loaddata dump.json`

Comment: Have added the field in the model and in the database. The field has a foreign key. But I still get "unknown column in field list"!

Comment: Hi. I'm now trying to re-create my db, but get -" The row in table 'tabel' with primary key '6' has an invalid foreign key... But the database is empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the tables created in the database and you are not using south there are two options. The first one is to delete the tables and re-create them again using syncdb and the second is to make the schema changes manually(this is probably going to be hard and ugly).

As for the south ... do not think of it as some unstable third party app that you may not need. Even that it has some limitations it is an extremely useful tool and you will only benefit form using it so don't worry and go ahead with it.

Comment: Do I have to change anything on the scripts server or db if a use South? Or is just on my computer that south is needed. Because if it just on my computer, I can use it.

Comment: Backup your model files. Return them in a state that they match the structure in the database and then follow http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/ConvertingAnApp
Once your apps are converted to south apply your model changes and run schemamigration and migrate.